# Data is not displaying in custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, custom-lists

I have created a custom listview which gets data from the database. With the help of toast i am able to see that all values are coming properly but these values are not shown in Listview. ListViewAdapter class is working properly.
Here is my mainActivity code

```
    public class FamilyInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ListView lv_fam_memb;
    ArrayList<String>namelist,agelist,edulist,rellist;
    ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
    String id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_family_info);
        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        id=bundle.getString("headid");
        namelist=new ArrayList<>();
        agelist=new ArrayList<>();
        edulist=new ArrayList<>();
        rellist=new ArrayList<>();
        lv_fam_memb=findViewById(R.id.lv_fam_member);
        new GetMydata().execute();
        listViewAdapter=new ListViewAdapter(FamilyInfo.this,namelist,agelist,edulist,rellist);
        lv_fam_memb.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    } public class GetMydata extends AsyncTask{
       MyConnection myConnection;
       Connection connection;
       Statement statement;
       ResultSet resultSet;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();
           pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FamilyInfo.this);
           pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
           pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
           pDialog.setCancelable(false);
           pDialog.show();
       }

       @Override
       protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
           myConnection=new MyConnection();
           connection=myConnection.DatabaseConncetion1();
           try {
               statement=connection.createStatement();
               resultSet=statement.executeQuery("select MEM_NAME,MEM_AGE,MEM_EDU,MEM_REl from FAMILY_NO where HEAD_ID="+id);

           } catch (SQLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
           super.onPostExecute(o);
           try {
               while (resultSet.next())
               {
                   namelist.add(resultSet.getString(1));
                   agelist.add(resultSet.getString(2));
                   edulist.add(resultSet.getString(3));
                   rellist.add(resultSet.getString(4));
                  }
               pDialog.dismiss();



           } catch (SQLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }

}
```

Please tell me what is missing, thank you :)

Comment: post your adapter code here

Comment: You are not notifying the change made to the list to the adapter 
just call adapter_name.notifyDataSetChanged(); after the while completion it will notify the changes and it will display data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have called `setAdapter()` in `onCreate()` with empty List. .
Now when you load data you need to call `notifydatasetChanged()` in Adapter . See the code below.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    super.onPostExecute(o);
    try {
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            namelist.add(resultSet.getString(1));
            agelist.add(resultSet.getString(2));
            edulist.add(resultSet.getString(3));
            rellist.add(resultSet.getString(4));
        }
        pDialog.dismiss();
        listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: but you mistake here ADM

Comment: list is not empty NewBee executed asynktask then set adapter to view

Comment: can you explain i m not getting why notifysetchnaged worked

Comment: First of all all 4 lists are empty see the `onCreate()`. And second thing there is no sense of using 4 lists for single adapter. The OP should use a POJO class for it .

Comment: @VineshChauhan The `Async` part of `AsyncTask` means _asynchronous_. Execution in `onCreate()` proceeds immediately after the `new GetMydata().execute()` call; i.e., it doesn't wait for the `AsyncTask` to complete.

Answer (score -1):

you have to notify your **adapter** whenever you change the data of the list by `notifyDataSetChanged()` after changing the data